# Show in activity message from BroadcastReceiver when change connectivity

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I have BroadCastReceiver that control my connectivity.
I would, when I lost connection, show message, but not generic toast, but a "layout" that I designed.
my broadcast is a generic broadCast for connection:

```
public class ConnectivityChangeReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
        ConnectivityManager cm =(ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo()!=null){
            Toast.makeText(context, "Connected to Internet", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        else{
            /** HERE INSTEAD OF TOAST, IWOULD DISPLAY MESSAGE ON ACTIVITY **/
            Toast.makeText(context, "not connection", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            Log.i("INTERNET", "---------------------> Internet Disconnected. ");
        }
    }

}
```

And my "no_connection_layout"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="52dp"
        android:text="No InterNeT"
        android:id="@+id/no_connection"
        android:layout_weight="1"

        android:layout_gravity="center|top"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/holo_green_dark"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        />
</FrameLayout>
```

Is there a way for show this layout indistinctly current activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

    //Obviously cleanup where you do this stuff, to make it efficient
    //If your context is a fragment you need to cast to fragment and then do getActivity instead
    final View noConnectionBanner = ((Activity) context).findViewById(R.id.no_connection)
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

    if (cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null) {
        noConnectionBanner.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    } else {
        noConnectionBanner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello nick, thankyou for reply.
my context is receiver because I have register Broadcast from manifest.
So, I can't cast Context, I have to register broadcast in all activities?

Comment: If you have no way to access your activity then yes, the simplest fix is to register your br in onResume and unregister in onPause for each activity. Or if your activity is singleInstance you're ab;e to send the new state as an intent

Answer (score 0):

Just trigger a function and write the view elements that you want to show.

```
  public class ConnectionBroadReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager)
                context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);

        NetworkInfo netInfo = cm.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (netInfo != null && netInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting()) {
        } else {
            Visibler();

        }


    }

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    this.connectionBroadReceiver = new ConnectionBroadReceiver();
    registerReceiver(this.connectionBroadReceiver, new IntentFilter(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION));
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    unregisterReceiver(this.connectionBroadReceiver);
    super.onPause();
}
```

Then inside main program,

```
   @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    floatingActionButton = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.floater);
}

private void Visibler() {
    floatingActionButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Create a Global Boolean and make it true when There is internet Connectivity and false when it is not connected.
And then create a async task class doinBackground method and check it continuosly when the variable changes and from postExecute method you can make changes in the UI. if you need more help pm me .

Comment: Also an asyncTask is designed to run once, so what happens on the second connectivity change?

Comment: Thanx man you increased my knowledge . :D i was just helping with what i kniw